# FirebaseML Vision not working well with image captured using device camera

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, firebase-mlkit

I am referring to sample code

[https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-ios/#0

give here to detect text in image.
If I run this code with my invoice image (scanned document) it works fine. But when I go and capture image of invoice printout it do not give me any accurate results. 
In given sample I have just launched camera and given captured image to the

```
runTextRecognition(with: imgSelectedImage)
```

Help me to figure out the issue

**UPDATE**

```
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    imgSelectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    runTextRecognition(with: imgSelectedImage)
    }


[![func runTextRecognition(with image: UIImage) {
  let visionImage = VisionImage(image: image)
    textDetector.detect(in: visionImage) { features, error in
      self.processResult(from: features, error: error)
    }
  }

 func processResult(from text: \[VisionText\]?, error: Error?) {
    removeFrames()
    guard let features = text, let image = imageView.image else {
      return
    }
    for text in features {
      if let block = text as? VisionTextBlock {
        for line in block.lines {
          for element in line.elements {
            self.addFrameView(
              featureFrame: element.frame,
              imageSize: image.size,
              viewFrame: self.imageView.frame,
              text: element.text
            )
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It could be orientation - can you pull together a minimal snippet and link the image you're having trouble with?

Comment: @IanBarber have updated the question. Added code and image please check.

Comment: @IanBarber have you checked this?

Comment: Can you try taking the photo with different orientation? Depending on the orientation and the camera, you may even be getting the image reverse.